# Angular 7 to dotnetcore 2.1 web api call gives no response

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

below is the code from login.component.ts,

```
login() {
const val = this.form.value;

if (val.email && val.password) {
  this.authService.login(val.email, val.password)
    .subscribe(
      data => {

        if (data && data.Token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in 
          //between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log("user logged in");
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        } else {
          console.log("user not logged in");
        }

      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
 }
}
```

below is the code from angular service,

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
 return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + "Authenticate", { email, 
password }, httpOptions);
}
```

below is the code for dotnetcore 2.1 web api action,

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using API.Utilities;
using Business.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;


namespace API.Controllers
{
  [Authorize]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public UsersController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {          
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]User userParam)
    {
        var user = Authenticate(userParam.Email, userParam.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });

        return Ok(user);
    }



    public User Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        //////code goes

        return user;
    }


}
}
```

}

In fiddler always I can see my post request with length as -1. Not sure what is the problem any help?[image: attached fiddler screenshot for reference]

Below are from the startup.cs. Is there any flaw in my CORS Settings for dotnetcore2.1 WEB API solution

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).
            AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options => {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36000);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

Comment: are you getting a hit to your controller/action method from Angular?

Comment: I could not hit WEB API controller action breakpoint when called from angular.

Comment: For this reuqest, it seems to process `CORS`, have you enabled cors in `Starup.cs` like `            app.UseCors(opt => {
                opt.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowCredentials();
            });
`

Comment: Yes, I have enabled CORS.But seems not applied because some times in console i could see cors blocked but that error comes only after some time out

Comment: I have added startup.cs for reference

Comment: post full controller are u using route at controller & method level by any chance ?

Comment: Hi @saj,@Tao Zhou i have added full controller here.

Comment: [Authorize] are you sending any cookies or header to authroize?

Comment: Login is decorated with [AllowAnonymous] annotation. So i am not sending anything except content type in header as http options in angular

Comment: Use POSTMAN to sure your controller is working fine.

Comment: from angular application even get methods also failing so i tried the same get in browser and those were wroking.Still i will try post in postman.

Comment: In fiddler i could see there is no request with Post method type.

Comment: For the screen shot, it seems to be related with cors, but it seems you have configured it. Is there any complete demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Tao Zhou can u give ur mail id. I will share you the complete code.

Comment: You can create the demo with no sensitive information which could reproduce your issue, and then share us your demo project here.

Comment: sorry for delay.I have created API sample and it is at below location. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j4MQxD2tpGSg1Y0SknUqNdZ5CWVMvSyD

Comment: Doesn't look like the TS object you're passing in your Angular services post method is made correctly. Should be key/value pairs. Something like { username: email, pass : password } should work. Could be wrong, it's been a minute since I've used Angular. But I think it should be key/value pairs.

Comment: AddCors ABOVE useMvc; UseCors ABOVE UseStaticFiles...

Comment: have you tried to send an object User from angular instead of email, password than change your action to [HttpPost("Authenticate", Name = "Authenticate")] and route controller to [Route("api/users")] @Mahesh

Comment: `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` could cause problems. try to remove it

Comment: Seriously unable to understand but it suddenly started working. I have no pending changes in my local.

Comment: Got to know. It's because HTTP in base URL. When I updated my service base URL to HTTPS its working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take into consideration that your WEB API service is accesed from a different port than the one from your Angular UI. What hosts your UI in development mode is Angular Cli. This means is that enabling CORS for your WEB API doesn't necessarily enable them for Angular's UI.

By the looks of the image you posted, your Web API's URL would be `http://localhost:44389` but the [referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) is `http://localhost:4200`.

One way to get around this at a development stage, is by adding to your ClientApp root folder a `proxyconfig.json` file with a similar configuration to:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
  "target": "https://localhost:44389",
  "secure": true,
  "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This way the browser interprets that requests from your Angular UI to your WEB API are from the same origin.

If your WEB API and Angular UI are to be hosted in the same server in production mode I would recommend avoiding CORS. Here's a good article about the subject: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c

Note: you may need to serve the `proxyconfig.json` file, here's how: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1259121/%2FTips%2F1259121%2FAngular-Proxy-Configuration-for-API-Calls

Comment: when i directly updated base url in service.ts with https it's started working.

Comment: That is good to know. But note that if both, Web API and Angular UI are going to be hosted by the same server in production, CORS is not the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please let me know if you have any alternative.

Comment: Of course, read the **PRODUCTION APROACH** section of the article I shared in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I once had an issue where I had controllers in the same directory as my virtual api route. It looks like this *may* be the same issue for you. You have:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
  [Authorize]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class UsersController : BaseController
{
```

Now, my assumption is (from your namespace) that directory your controller is in is: `api/{controllerName}`.

Then your api route is: `api/[controller]`. This means that you now you may have an actual directory and a virtual directory at the same route. When you try to hit your api, dotnet is confused as to whether you are try to access the directory files or the api route. In some circumstances this returns a `401` error others (depending on the browser) will return you nothing.

You can test this theory pretty easily by changing your api route to something like `test/[controller]` temporarily and then try and hit it.

If this resolves it, then you have 2 options:

1. Change your api route.
2. Change your controller directory.

Comment: Changed to test/[controller] but still not working. Seems mine is different issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason is HTTP in base URL. When I updated my base URL to HTTPS it's started working.