# I am unable to have a connection from my angular frontend to my C# backend. What is the reason for this?

Tags: c#, angular, powershell

I'm writing an angular application. The main problem I have right now is that when I have to connect my frontend application with my backend server that it's unable to do so and that I get error 0. I have also uploaded another application that returns a similar error. Given that error 0 indicates that the problem could be literally anything I would like to know what causes the problem.

As far as I know the problem can't be there because of my backend not properly working. That's because my application runs with Swagger and Swagger doesn't have any notable problem with returning code that has been parsed in JSON.

Thus it must be my frontend. However that's also unlikely, because it works well until it has to connect to the backend. (In my code, that would be until class authentication.service.ts line 64 for checking the username and until authentication.service.ts line 40 for registering a user).

I've already asked my Norton antivirus to stop doing anything to see if my application is not working due to my antivirus, but it turns out that my antivirus wasn't doing anything to stop my frontend from connecting to my backend.

If some code is running wrong it has to be code in this method:

```
checkUserNameAvailability = (username: string): Observable<boolean> => {
    //    console.log(username);
    return this.http.get<boolean>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/User/checkusername`,
      {
        params: { username }
      }
    ).pipe(catchError(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return of(null);
    }))
  }
```

This is code in authentication.service.ts from line 62 until line 73.

I'll link to my github repositories below:

Angular frontend: https://github.com/GuylianBollon/AngularFrontendWebIV
C# backend: https://github.com/GuylianBollon/CbackendWebIV

Here's another thing I found:
After I connect my angular frontend to my C# backend and directly after it check the connection on the command prompt the following is generated. (Note: 44392 is the SSL Port of my C# backend).

```
C:\Users\Hp>netstat -a -n | findstr 44392
  TCP    0.0.0.0:44392          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:44392             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:44392            [::1]:53942            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:53942            [::1]:44392            ESTABLISHED
```

After I wait for about 1 minute the following is generated:

```
C:\Users\Hp>netstat -a -n | findstr 44392
  TCP    0.0.0.0:44392          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:44392             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:53942            [::1]:44392            TIME_WAIT
```

Not sure if this is normal or not, but I thought this was interesting.

Here's also the json of my proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": "https",
      "port": 44392
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "warn"
  }
}
```

When I open the browser after I connect my angular frontend to my C# backend, write something on the username field and wait 2 minutes the following is generated:

authentication.service.ts:70 
1.  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "/api/User/checkusername", ok: false, …}
1.  error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
2.  headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
3.  message: "Http failure response for /api/User/checkusername: 0 Unknown Error"
4.  name: "HttpErrorResponse"
5.  ok: false
6.  status: 0
7.  statusText: "Unknown Error"
8.  url: "/api/User/checkusername"
9.  **proto**: HttpResponseBase

api/User/checkusername?username=abc:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: I would: 1) check if the backed is indeed working correctly, using Postman (or compatible); if yes, then proceed to 2) running the Angular app, check Network tab in dev tools, and find the differences between request sent by Angular and the correct one sent by Postman.

Comment: Does your `api/User/checkusername` endpoint return data when invoked through postman?

Comment: @akg179 The service returns endpoint data when invoked through postman. While the database was empty I gave him the link to https://localhost:44392/api/User/checkusername?username=abc and he returned true, which is the correct answer for that question.

Comment: @mbojko The difference between the 2 is obviously that the one sent by angular refers to port number 4200 while the one by postman refers to port number 44392. In angular I've also written a proxy.conf.json file that is called whenever npm start is invoked. I forgot indeed to mention that. I'll add it.

Comment: Have u checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804439/angular-7-to-dotnetcore-2-1-web-api-call-gives-no-response) answer if it helps.

Comment: @akg179 I did. There was one thread I found interesting (that one with duplicate api). I tried to rename it, but it still failed. The rest was with things I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your proxy configuration file, a fixed version:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 44392
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "warn"
  }
}
```

Notice the colon (:) after `https:`, which is missing in your version.